# Why doesn't Kryptex inside Wine recognize CPUs and GPUs?

Tags: linux, usb, wine, hardware-detection, kryptex

When I try to run Kryptex inside Wine on Lubuntu, which is installed on a USB drive (not in live mode), either the program freezes during benchmarking or it finishes without finding any hardware on the computer. Could it be the problem that I installed the OS on a USB drive? Thank you for your help!

Comment: The software isn't mentioned at the WineHQ database so who knows? Not all software runs with Wine, FYI.